# How to put two divs next to each other?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I need to build a list that has text on the left side and a photo on the right side.

**This is my HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="one">
        <p>This is text to be displayed in this div. It can be long, or short, or anything.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">photo here</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="one">
        <p>#2: This is text to be displayed in this div...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">photo here</div>   
</div>
```

**This is the CSS:**

```
div.wrap {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    overflow: auto;
}
div.one {
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}
div.two {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
}
```

**The problem:** http://jsfiddle.net/egXuq/

**What I tried:** 
I studied some solutions on SO, and...

- put `overflow: auto` in the parent div
- floated `div.two` right
  --> still one below the other... need help, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will also need to float `div.one`.

```
div.one {
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    float: left;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/egXuq/1/)

--

If you're curious about floats or element positioning, you can read more on the [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) The simple explanation is this:

> When an element is floated it is taken out of the normal flow of the
>   document. It is shifted to the left or right until it touches the edge
>   of it's containing box or another floated element.

Comment: Oh, that's easy ;-) Now, can I have it that `div.one` would give space to `div.two`and the text within `div.one`would wrap?

Comment: Sure, without getting too complicated, the simple answer would be to add a `%` width to `div.one`, like `width: 65%`, for example.

Comment: OK, could you point me to a source where it is getting more complicated? I think the % will do it for the moment, though, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `div.wrap` doesn't have a width. Is this going into a page that will have responsive design, or one where you will be setting explicit widths?

I went with a fixed width solution for you, as responsive design would be best done with a library like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). I gave `div.wrap` a width, then `div.one` a width and floated both `div.one` and `div.two` to the left and added clear to `div.wrap`.

[fixed width Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6AtW/1/)

Comment: ok, I see. I don't want to use fixed `width` though, and no bootstrap yet.

Answer (score 1):

Does the structure with the divs have to be this way?
If you swap the inner divs, the photo will happily float to the right.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="two">photo here</div>
    <div class="one"><p>This is text to be displayed in this div. It can be long, or short, or anything.</p></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sXMy4/

Comment: ok, interesting, too. I'd have to use `span` then instead of `div`.